# Type 'Promise<AddResult>' must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I have something like these

```js
for await (const entry of ipfs.add(
    globSource(dirPath, { recursive: true, ignore }),
  ))
```

Problem this results in a typescript is:

> Type 'Promise' must have a 'Symbol.asyncIterator' method that returns an async iterator.ts(2504)
> uploadDirToIpfs.ts(38, 29): Did you forget to use 'await'?
> Argument of type 'AsyncGenerator<{ path: string; content: ReadStream | undefined; mode: any; mtime: any; } | { path: string; mode: number | undefined; mtime: MtimeLike | undefined; }, void, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ImportCandidate'.
> Type 'AsyncGenerator<{ path: string; content: ReadStream | undefined; mode: any; mtime: any; } | { path: string; mode: number | undefined; mtime: MtimeLike | undefined; }, void, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncIterable'.
> The types returned by 'Symbol.asyncIterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'Promise<IteratorResult<{ path: string; content: ReadStream | undefined; mode: any; mtime: any; } | { path: string; mode: number | undefined; mtime: MtimeLike | undefined; }, void>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IteratorResult<Uint8Array, any>>'.

> Type 'IteratorResult<{ path: string; content: ReadStream | undefined; mode: any; mtime: any; } | { path: string; mode: number | undefined; mtime: MtimeLike | undefined; }, void>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<Uint8Array, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult<{ path: string; content: ReadStream | undefined; mode: any; mtime: any; } | { path: string; mode: number | undefined; mtime: MtimeLike | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<Uint8Array, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult<{ path: string; content: ReadStream | undefined; mode: any; mtime: any; } | { path: string; mode: number | undefined; mtime: MtimeLike | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult'.
> Type '{ path: string; content: ReadStream | undefined; mode: any; mtime: any; } | { path: string; mode: number | undefined; mtime: MtimeLike | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Uint8Array'.

Any idea what exactly I have to change ?

Comment: What is `ipfs.add`, and what does it return? As the error says, it is not returning an async iterator (which is needed in this construct).

Comment: It sounds like `ipfs.add` returns a promise for an array, so you would need to use `for (const entry of await ipfs.add(globSource(dirPath, { recursive: true, ignore }))) …` (or `const entries = await ipfs.add(globSource(dirPath, { recursive: true, ignore })); for (const entry of entries) …` for clarity)